# Question for an abelian extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field, galois-extensions

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be real algebraic numbers satisfying $\alpha+\beta\notin\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha^{3}+\beta^{3}\in\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> Let $K\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha+\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> Suppose that the Galois group $G:=\textrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian.
>
> Show that:
>
> - $x := \alpha\omega+\beta\omega^{2}$
> - $y := \alpha\omega^{2}+\beta\omega$
>
> are elements of $K$
>
> where $\omega\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\omega^{3}=1,\omega\neq1$.

We find that

- $x + y = -(\alpha + \beta)$
- $x \cdot y = \alpha^2 - \alpha \beta + \beta^2 = \frac{\alpha^3 + \beta^3}{\alpha + \beta}$
- $\alpha\beta=\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^{3}-(\alpha^{3}+\beta^{3})}{3(\alpha+\beta)}\in K$.
- The polynomial $P(X)=X^{3}-3\alpha\beta\cdot X-(\alpha^{3}+\beta^{3})$ has $\alpha+\beta$ as a root.
- The terms $x$ and $y$ look like the cubic Lagrange Resolvent.

but how can we finish?

Comment: (1) is wrong. In fact, $K$ is generated by $\alpha+\beta$ *and its conjugates*. Now, can you guess what the conjugates of $\alpha+\beta$ are?

Comment: @Wojowu I don't understand your comment. Since $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ with abelian group $G(K/\mathbb{Q})$, the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta)$ of $K$ is a normal extension over $\mathbb{Q}$. So, I had concluded that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta)$. Is it false?

Comment: Something is a bit off. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real, so is $K$ by item (1). But then we have the problem that $\alpha\omega+\beta\omega^2=(\alpha-\beta)\omega-\beta$ is not real unless $\alpha=\beta$, which is then forced to be the case. But then $(\alpha+\beta)^3=8\alpha^3=4(\alpha^3+\beta^3)=q\in\Bbb{Q}$. Implying that $\alpha+\beta$ is an irrational cube root of a rational. Violating the assumption about abelianity.

Comment: What I'm concluding is that either A) $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{R}$ or B) $\alpha\omega+\beta\omega^2\in K$ must be dropped.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your concerning. It seems to be someone's problem, but it seems to be an error as you pointed out. By the way, 
If the condition of this problem is modified properly, then what do you think the problem is for? Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the conditions are contradictory.

As $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian, every subfield of $K$ is Galois, thus $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta)$. In particular $K \subset \mathbb{R}$.

But $(x-y)^2=(\alpha-\beta)^2(\omega-\omega^2)^2$ can be written as $(x+y)^2-4xy \in K$. Now, $(\alpha-\beta)^2=(\alpha^2-\alpha\beta+\beta^2)-\alpha\beta$ is already in $K$, so $(\omega-\omega^2)^2=2\omega-2 \in K$ so that $\omega \in K$. We get a contradiction, to which the only escape is when $\alpha=\beta$ is the cubic root of a rational number (which stll isn't abelian).

Comment: I don’t think $(X-x)(X-y)$ necessarily has coefficients in $K$.

Comment: @TokenToucan: But $-x-y=\alpha+\beta \in K$, while $xy=\frac{\alpha^3+\beta^3}{\alpha+\beta} \in K$ from the OP...

Comment: No, $\alpha+\beta$ is not in $K$, as stated in the question. Similarly $xy$ is not in $K$ because it is the quotient of something in $K$ ($\alpha^3 +\beta^3$) and something not in $K$ ($\alpha+\beta$). Well, unless they’re zero but then there’s not much to do.

Comment: @TokenToucan: I read in the question that $K$ is the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha+\beta$. So it seems to mean that $\alpha+\beta$ is in $K$?

Comment: Oh I see, I mixed up the ground fields!

Comment: Although I *did* mix up stuff too, actually... I was so sure that $P$ was rational...

Comment: I saw this just pop up on the same page and oddly the notation is very similar. If you mix it with the question above I think you actually get something sensible (but one probably has to ignore the bit about alpha and beta being real I think). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805300/the-roots-of-the-general-quartic-in-abc-form