# The roots of the general quartic in $a+b+c$ form.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, permutations, galois-theory

The roots of $x^3+qx+r$ are
$$1 := \alpha+\beta$$
$$2 := \,\,\omega\alpha+\omega^2\beta$$
$$3 := \;\;\omega^2\alpha+\omega\beta$$

where $1$, $2$ and $3$ are defined to be labels for the picture below and

$$\omega=-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$
$$\alpha^3=\frac{1}{2}(-r+\sqrt{D})$$
$$D=r^2+\frac{4}{27}q^3$$
$$\beta = -\frac{1}{3} \frac{q}{\alpha}. $$

The proof for the solutions of the cubic in these terms can be found in "A First Course in Abstract Algebra with Applications (Third Edition)" by Joseph J. Rotman, Theorem 5.4  on page 438.

We can draw a triangle with labels $1$, $2$, and $3$ as vertices and proceed to map all the symmetries of the triangle.

[image]

Now we can ask, since each vertex is labeled with the roots of the cubic: what are the maps in terms of $\omega,\alpha,\beta$ that would allows us to transform a root to another thereby interchanging the labels to get another symmetry of the triangle? Say for example, from 123 to 312?

$$
e: \begin{cases} 
          \alpha \mapsto \alpha \\
          \beta \mapsto \beta
  \end{cases}
$$

$$
r: \begin{cases} 
          \alpha \mapsto \omega^2\alpha \\
          \beta \mapsto \omega\beta
  \end{cases}
$$

$$
r^2: \begin{cases} 
          \alpha \mapsto \omega\alpha \\
          \beta \mapsto \omega^2\beta
  \end{cases}
$$

$$
s_0: \begin{cases} 
          \alpha \mapsto \omega\beta \\
          \beta \mapsto \omega^2\alpha
  \end{cases}
$$

$$
s_1: \begin{cases} 
          \alpha \mapsto \omega^2\beta \\
          \beta \mapsto \omega\alpha
  \end{cases}
$$

$$
s_2: \begin{cases} 
          \alpha\omega \mapsto \omega\beta \\
          \alpha\beta \mapsto \omega\beta
  \end{cases}
$$

We can check that we can go from 123 to 312 by applying the $r$ mapping to the labels, which corresponds to rotation by -120 degrees:

$$
\begin{cases} 
  r(\;Label\;1\;) &= r(\alpha+\beta)               &= r(\alpha)+r(\beta)                   &= \omega^2\alpha+\omega\beta &=\;Label\;3\\
  r(\;Label\;2\;) &= r(\omega\alpha+\omega^2\beta) &= \omega r(\alpha)+\omega^2 r(\beta)   &=    \omega (\omega^2\alpha)+\omega^2 (\omega\beta)     &= \alpha+\beta = \;Label\;1\\ 
  r(\;Label\;3\;) &= r(\omega^2\alpha+\omega\beta) &= \omega^2 r(\alpha) + \omega r(\beta) &=
  \omega^2 (\omega^2\alpha) + \omega (\omega\beta) &= \omega\alpha + \omega^2\beta = \; Label\; 2
\end{cases}
$$

So, $$r(123)\mapsto 312$$

Now my question is, where may I find the solution of the general quartic $$x^4+px^2+qx+r$$ in terms of one of the roots being in the form $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ analogous to the way the solution to the cubic above has one of the roots in the form $\alpha+\beta$?

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer but check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_by_Lagrange_resolvent

Comment: I don't think the analogy works quite that simply. The Galois theoretic way of solving a quartic is a bit more complicated. The passage from $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to the roots of the cubic (and back) is simple. If the roots of a quartic are denoted $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$, then the quanties $\alpha=r_1r_2+r_3r_4$, $\beta=r_1r_3+r_2r_4$ and $\gamma=r_1r_4+r_2r_3$ are the zeros of the cubic polynomial $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$. Expanding that out we see that the coefficients are symmetric polynomials of the $r_i$s.

Comment: (cont'd) Therefore we can read the coefficients of that cubic (called the resolvent cubic) from the quartic we started with. This means that we can solve for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ with the cubic formula. This is then enough to find the $r_i$s, but that is another step. For example $(r_1+r_2)(r_3+r_4)=\beta+\gamma$, $(r_1+r_2)+(r_3+r_4)=0$ (for the depressed quartic), allowing us to solve for $r_1+r_2$ and $r_3+r_4$ et cetera.